# Scene in Jerry's House in The King of Comedy

Tags: plot-explanation, the-king-of-comedy

One of the funniest - and cringiest - scenes in *The King of Comedy* is the scene where Rupert visits Jerry's house uninvited, waits for him to get back, and ultimately gets kicked out by Jerry, which is what drives him to kidnap Jerry subsequently. I've always wondered something about this scene: is it real? Does Rupert actually visit Jerry's house, or is it just one of his delusions? There are two reasons for this:

1. Jerry never invites Rupert to his house in real life, but only in one of Rupert's other delusions. It's true that Rupert often acts on his delusions in real life, but this is the only case in the movie where he takes a step this big.
2. More importantly, Rita's hair. In the scene in Jerry's house, Rita has short hair, whereas in the rest of the movie her hair is longer. This could perhaps be Rupert's idealized picture for his future -- being married to Rita -- because the short hair makes her look more mature.

Any thoughts? If this scene is truly a figment of Rupert's imagination, it paints an even more concerning picture of Rupert - because this means he is pushed to take the drastic step of kidnapping Jerry  because of something that didn't even really happen.